# Solve logistic problem with graph - fitting boxes

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

Suppose you have $n$ boxes, each of which falls into one of the $k$ sizes, and you want to nest smaller ones into larger ones, such that no two boxes $A$ and $B$ are nested inside the same box, if neither $A$ contains $B$ nor $B$ contains $A$. Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to nest the boxes, such that the number of boxes visible is minimized (i.e., use up the least space)?

Comment: It seems like there's a natural greedy algorithm here; do you have an example to show that the greedy algorithm fails?

Answer (score 1):

There is. Suppose the number of boxes of each size is respectively $x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_k$. Then the number of boxes visible is the largest of these numbers.

**Proof:** We cannot nest any box in a smaller box. In a larger box, exactly one such box fits. In short, in each visible box is at most one box of a given size So the number of boxes visible is at least the largest of  $x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_k$.

I take size $k$ to be the largest, and size 1 to be the smallest. Now just take all largest boxes of size $k$. These are visisible. Put a box of size $k-1$ in each of them, or stop when they run out. If there are boxes leftover, put them as a new boxes that are visible. Repeat and finish.

Reading input takes $O(n)$ operations. Then counting the number of duplicates takes $O(n)$ operations. Sorting takes $O(n \ln n)$ operations. Printing the output takes $O(n)$ operations. Total is $O(n \ln n)$, which is polynomial.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but if you have size $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$ and boxes $A, B, C$ with the respective sizes, why can't you nest $A$ in $B$, then nest $B$ (containing $A$) in $C$?

Comment: @user90593 You can. So?

Comment: Could you give a small example to illustrate the proof?

Comment: @ what do you mean by 'a box of size 3, containing one of size 2, containing one of size 3'?

Comment: Allow me to completely rewrite that comment. I meant: "
 
1 box of size 3, 2 boxes of size 2, 2 boxes of size 1. Then we have a box of size 3, containing one of size 2, containing one of size 1. We also have one of size 2, containing one of size 1." I really made too much mistakes with that one.